# Array in Api's Query String

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-apicontroller

Using WebClient do send an array to an ApiController via query string I get the error 400.

The api method looks like

```
public IHttpActionResult List([FromUri] Model model)
```

In the Model class I have

```
public int[] Ids { get; set; }
```

In the client side the code looks like:

```
webClient.QueryString.Add("ids", "1");
webClient.QueryString.Add("ids", "2");
...
await webClient.DownloadStringTaskAsync(url);
```

If I send just one "ids" parameter the code works fine, but not with two or more.

I found that the client creates the url like "url?ids=1,2" instead "url?ids=1&ids=2".

Is there some configuration I missed?

Comment: Is Ids your only property inside your model?

Comment: Which version is this of Asp.Net Core?

Comment: I think the problem is that ASP.NET doesn't create GET strings with duplicate key names per default. You could try to manually generate a GET URL

Comment: I'm using .Net 4.6, not Core.
Yes @Moray but it's strange that Api don't work with WebClient in the same .Net version. If I create the query string by hand it works.

Comment: I found that is required code this solution out of the box: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9981330/pass-an-array-of-integers-to-asp-net-web-api

Answer (score 1):

`WebClient` will automatically turn multiple values with the same key into a comma separated string. You can change this behavior, see: [How to build WebClient querystring with duplicate keys?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17415169/how-to-build-webclient-querystring-with-duplicate-keys)

I would recommend using `HttpClient` instead of `WebClient` though.

Comment: Completly agree with using `HttpClient` instead of the legacy `WebClient`